# Symfony Form times out when trying to populate $form object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

The below Symfony form works fine in development when I only have a few records of each entity in the database. However, once I connect it to an extract of my production database the page times out.

The size of the database tables in this extract are bigger (around 800 records each) but nothing to justify it timing out completely. I'm assuming that the problem is a misunderstanding of how best to populate `$batch` in

## The controller:

```
public function batchInvoicesAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $members = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->findActiveMembers();
    $batch = new InvoiceBatch();

    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $invoice = new Invoice();
        $invoice->setMemberId($member);
        $invoice->setSelected(True);
        $invoice->setCreatedate(new \Datetime());
        $invoice->setAmount($member->getDefaultinvoiceamount());
        $invoice->setCurrency($member->getDefaultinvoicecurrency());
        $invoice->setinvoicebatchid($batch);
        $batch->addInvoiceId($invoice);
        # exit(VarDumper::dump($batch));
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(InvoiceBatchType::class, $batch);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && ($form->isValid())) {

        $batchform = $form->getData();

        foreach ($batchform->getInvoiceids() as $invoiceform) {
            if ($invoiceform->getSelected() == False) {
                $batchform->removeInvoiceId($invoiceform);
            } else {
                $em->persist($invoiceform);
            }
        }
        $em->persist($batchform);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('view_monthly_invoices');
    }

    return $this->render('invoices/new.batch.invoice.html.twig', array(
        'page_title' => 'Invoices',
        'message' => 'Batch loading of invoices',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

## The repository function code is:

```
public function findActiveMembers()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery
        (
            'SELECT m
             FROM AppBundle:Members m
             WHERE m.active= :active
             ORDER BY m.familyname1, m.familyname2, m.firstname'
        )
        ->setParameter('active' ,true)
        ->getResult();
}
```

In case it's of any help:

### 1. Vardump of the partial `$batch`:

```
{#1022 ▼
  #id: null
  #invoice_ids: ArrayCollection {#1023 ▼
    -elements: array:1 [▼
      0 => Invoice {#1024 ▼
        #id: null
        #invoicebatch_id: InvoiceBatch {#1022}
        #member_id: Member {#1049 ▶}
        #payment_ids: ArrayCollection {#1027 ▶}
        #attendc_ids: ArrayCollection {#1025 ▶}
        #attende_ids: ArrayCollection {#1044 ▶}
        #bankreceipt: null
        #aggregate_payment: 0
        #selected: true
        #amount: "0.00"
        #currency: "S"
        #invoicedate: null
        #createdate: DateTime {#19571 ▶}
        #modifydate: null
        #billedmonth: null
        #description: null
      }
    ]
  }
```

### 2. My custom formTypes - this may be the problem as I'm still trying to get my head around FormTypes. The page only has one `InvoiceBatchType` which has an array of `Invoice_ids` used as CollectionType with `InvoiceForBulkType`:

```
class InvoiceBatchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('batchevent', TextType::class, array(
            ))
            ->add('invoice_ids', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => InvoiceForBulkType::class,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /* ... */
}

class InvoiceForBulkType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('selected', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label'    => ' ',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('member_id', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Member',
                    'choice_label' => 'FullName',
                    'label'=>'Member',
                    'disabled'=>true,
                )
            )
            ->add('amount', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Amount',
            ))
            ->add('currency',ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array('Soles' => 'S', 'Dollars' => 'D'),
                'choices_as_values' => true,
            ))
            ->add('invoicedate', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'data' => new \DateTime('now'),
                'format' => 'dd/MMM/yyyy',
                'label' => 'Date of invoice',
                'attr'=> array(
                    'class'=>'datepicker',
                )
            ))
            ->add('description', TextType::class, array(
                'required'=>false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Check if there is index created on column `active`

Comment: Also, are you assigning whole `$member` entity instead of just member id on line `$invoice->setMemberId($member);` ? Shouldn't it be something like `$invoice->setMemberId($member->getId());` ?

Comment: Also it seems you don't have proper relationships (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) set between entities `Invoice` and `InvoiceBatch`. Ideally you should do something like `$invoice->setBatch($batch);` and not `$invoice->setinvoicebatchid($batch);`

Comment: Also, are you saying, that in production your batch has 800 invoices, so you are trying to generate form for invoicebatch, which has collection of 800 invoice forms ? That seems a lot, but if you still want to do it, try increase max page load time with `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);` - just put this line at the beginning of the action. that should give you 10 minutes timeout...

Comment: Thank you very much @Miro I will work through your suggestions now :) I had tried `$invoice->setMemberId($member->getId());` before though however it gives me the error "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Invoice::setMemberId() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Member, integer given,". Is there a way around this as it would be much better to avoid that

Comment: I've updated my question with my `formType`s after your 3rd comment regarding `$invoice->setBatch($batch);`

Comment: have you tried basic debugging ? is the problem caused by slow SQL query of `findActiveMembers()` function ? or is it building of the form ? or is it displaying of the form in template ? there is too much questions here, i don't think you can get much help here, if you dont specify the problem more accurately.

Comment: I would try the Symfony debugger inferface but once page eventually loads (with the help of your `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);`) there is no Symfony debug bar(!) so I have no way (that I know of) of seeing where the problem is in Symfony. If I then submit the form to create the invoices, it eventually times out with "the application php5 has stopped unexpectedly"